# How to "unbold" this?

Tags: chapters, bold

I am using Texmaker and I am facing a small problem. I have included an abstract that is already on another .tex file under the name `abstract.tex`.

The thing is, my `abstract.tex` file template looks like this (please excuse me if it looks messy):

```
"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% ABSTRACT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter*{An Abstract of the Thesis of}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{tabbing}
\underline{\normalsize{Name Name Name}}\quad\quad
for\quad\quad\=\underline{Master of Engineering}\\
\>\underline{Major}: Electrical and Computer Engineering
\end{tabbing}
\vspace{0.5cm} Title: \underline{Title Title Title Title}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}

Abstract..."
```

When I include this file in my current `thesis.tex` file, using `\include{abstract}` I get the first line: **An Abstract of the Thesis of** in bold and my university's rules state that this sentence must not be in bold.

How can I unbold this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\chapter*{\normalfont An abstract of the Thesis of}` should do.

Comment: Is there a reason why you write `\chapter*{An Abstract of the Thesis of}` instead of, say, `\begin{center}\Huge An Abstract of the Thesis of}\end{center}`?

Comment: If you indent each line by four spaces (or use the curly bracket button with the text highlighted), it will be formatted as code and much easier for us to read.  Also, if you edit your question to include a minimum working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), it will be much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Mico this is the template by the library

Comment: @egreg a size of 16, would be what command? Thank you.

Comment: `\fontsize{16}{20}\selectfont`.

Comment: I mean just to the sentence inside \chapter*{..} and not in general

Comment: I mean just to the sentence inside \chapter*

Comment: @egreg Any actions to be taken?

Answer (score 17):

You can just type

```
\chapter*{\normalfont An Abstract of the Thesis of}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
```

(Switch comments for changing the alignment, but you already knew it; note `\protect` in front of `\numberline`.)

Anyway, I wouldn't do anything special: the abstract is just an unnumbered chapter and its heading should be the same as the other chapters.